# How to realize turning on/off 2812 LED strip from taranis with inav

Tags: inav

Please tell me how to realize feature - turning on/off the RGB backlight with the slider/toggle_switch at taranis(or other remote controller) in INAV.

I have 4 LED strips 2812 (matek) with 4 LEDs each. Each bar is connected to its own connector on the flight controller HGLRC F722.

The LEDs are working. When turned on, the quadrocopter shimmers with colors, and then they glow with white light. A special button(LED button) on the flight controller works, beacuse when i pressed it, the built-in backlight modes are switched. But I want to control it from my Taranis q7 in flight, turn lights on and off, or change colors.

First, I set up on my taranis so, that channel 5 is responsible for the rotary slider(S1). I made sure that in the receiver tab, it is on channel 5 that the change of the rotary slider is displayed.

In accordance with Paul's video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjML2r4dcIw ) and what is written in the hglrc manual ( https://www.hglrc.com/collections/fc/products/hglrc-zeus-f722-3-6s-f722-flight-controller ), I added a new rule in the mixer tab, for the servos. In the rule, I indicated that channel 5 is assigned to servo 1. afterwards I verified that port forwarding works. When I turn the slider, the outputs tab displays a change in value in the range 1000-2000 per servo1

In the configuration tab I have enabled LED_strip.

In the led_strip tab, I assigned numbers for the 16 LEDs.

Unfortunately, inav, unlike Betaflight, does not have the ability to choose a color change for a specific channel directly in the led_Strip tab. I don’t know exactly what to choose as the backlight mode for the 16 LEDs. I chose the state of the arming.

For some reason, when arming, the color does not change from green to blue. Other modes also do not works. The LEDs only light up in white.

In the mods tab, I switched on the Ledlow mod on channel 5.

All of the above actions were unsuccessful. Please help me figure it out.